# mysql query acces denied for user

Tags: android, mysql, json

I don't know why i can't connect with database

[index.php](http://pastie.org/9627496)

[DbFunctions.php](http://pastie.org/9627497)

```
 {"User message":false,"error":1,"success":0,"error_msg":"Error occured in Registartion","tag":"register"}

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query() [<a href='function.mysql-query'>function.mysql-query</a>]: Access denied for user 'u800018303'@'10.2.1.47' (using password: NO) in <b>/home/u800018303/public_html/DbFunctions.php</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query() [<a href='function.mysql-query'>function.mysql-query</a>]: A link to the server could not be established in <b>/home/u800018303/public_html/DbFunctions.php</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
{"tag":"register","success":0,"error":1,"User message":false,"error_msg":"Error occured in Registartion"}
```

Comment: I have problems with fields in database, i had 'not null' field but i didn't change it in my function, sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful :

1)
Most likely you forgot to call mysql_connect (or include the script that calls it). Consequently, the first call to mysql_query is trying to log in using (incomplete) automatic information and failing. The hint is that the error message is the one typically returned by mysql_connect when invalid credentials are supplied, but it's coming from mysql_query instead.

2)You certainly didn't have the same database user on both machines – so you need to set the used DB user and password in your applications configuration…